# Boot options in Windows boot manager not showing after Creators Update

Tags: boot, windows-10-v1703, bcdedit

Most of the times I need to boot with Hyper-V disabled, to use VirtualBox; but sometimes I need to use Hyper-V, so I set the boot options as follows with [BCDEDIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries#adding-a-new-boot-entry-in-windows-vista-and-later):

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "HYPER-V ON"
bcdedit /set {current} description "HYPER-V OFF"
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

This is how it looks after the changes:

```
Administrador de arranque de Windows
----------------------------------
Identificador           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  es-ES
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {2397c9c3-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
displayorder            {current}
                        {2397c9c7-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 10

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Hyper-V OFF
locale                  es-ES
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {2397c9c5-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {2397c9c3-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {2397c9c7-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Hyper-V ON
locale                  es-ES
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {2397c9c5-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {2397c9c3-89ca-11e3-a4dc-a86d76a65247}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

I could see the menu before the Creators Update. The update reset it to the defaults, so I reapplied the changes above. The system now boots without Hyper-V (so it uses the default option set) but the boot menu doesn't appear.

I changed the timeout to check if it was too fast for my eyes with no luck.

Any idea to make the boot menu appear again?

EDIT:

If I move the mouse during the boot, the system doesn't boot automatically. The screen is completely black but it's like the menu was there, waiting for me to choose an option. If I press Enter, it continues booting.
So I guess I can boot to the second option pressing ArrowDown once and Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fall Creators Update fixed that. The default *bcdedit* entry was reset but I could modify it, the second entry was preserved, and **the boot menu is shown** with both entries at the start.

---

Also note, if anybody else has this problem, a workaround can be to use [Hyper-V Switch](https://unclassified.software/en/apps/hypervswitch)